# How to capture form text fields as an array like a radio group

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I hope I ask this question correctly, and if not please direct me how to repair it. I have had it deleted as a post once already...

My goal is to submit a form with one drop down, with numbers like 100, 200, 300 (for how many T-shirts you want to order)...  Then depending on what is selected from the drop down have a series of text boxes (for number placement) that must add up to the selected number of shirts you want to order from the dropdown.

My idea is to capture all these text fields in an array, and send them off to a function to be added...

Can someone assist me please?

Here is the form code I know does not work, but I want it to work...

```
<form>

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="PoloDesign" value="100" id="PoloDesign_0" />
    100</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="PoloDesign" value="200" id="PoloDesign_1" />
    200</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="PoloDesign" value="300" id="PoloDesign_2" />
    300</label>
  <br />


  <input type="text" name="name[1]" id="name1" value="{$name1}"/>
  <input type="text" name="name[1]" id="name2" value="{$name2}"/>
  <input type="text" name="name[1]" id="name3" value="{$name3}"/>
  <input type="text" name="name[1]" id="name4" value="{$name4}"/>
  <input type="text" name="name[1]" id="name5" value="{$name5}"/>
  <input type="text" name="name[1]" id="name6" value="{$name6}"/>
  <input type="text" name="name[1]" id="name7" value="{$name7}"/>

  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>


</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change each

```
name="name[1]"
```

To

```
name="name[]"
```

Then the fields are posted as an array you can iterate through in PHP

```
if (is_array($_POST['name']):
    foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key=>$field):
        // do something here
         $yourKey = $key +1;
         $yourValue = $field;
```

Comment: wonderful, thank you.  I did attempt to have the number inside the array brackets....  but for whatever reason it never came out on the other end...


I would like ot know one other thing if you please.  inside the {value}  should I put {$name[1]} and if so, how does PHP know what value to place where?

Comment: Php numbers the array keys from 0,1,2... In the order the fields are posted!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code a little and tried to make it work using regular expression:

```
<?php
  $name_array = preg_grep('/name[1-9]*/', $_GET);
?>
```

So, basically it checks all submitted variables and creates array from all variables that have name at start and a number at end. So, the form part should change to look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" value="{$name1}"/>
<input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" value="{$name2}"/>
<input type="text" name="name3" id="name3" value="{$name3}"/>
<input type="text" name="name4" id="name4" value="{$name4}"/>
<input type="text" name="name5" id="name5" value="{$name5}"/>
<input type="text" name="name6" id="name6" value="{$name6}"/>
<input type="text" name="name7" id="name7" value="{$name7}"/>
```

I tested on Apache2 and PHP 5.3